# How to increment and decrement within a vector in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, increment, decrement

Is there an easier way to create a such a vector b=[1,3,5,7,9,7,5,3,1]?

What I did was, I basically divided the vector into the increasing and decreasing parts and used horzcat as follows:

```
a=horzcat((1:2:9),(7:-2:1));

disp(a);
```

However, this doesn't seem very efficent.
Is there a simpler way of doing this, without having to declare and concatanate two vectors?

Thanks.

Comment: The code seems very efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not terribly inefficient, no. However, you don't need to call `horzcat` by name:

```
a = [1:2:9 7:-2:1]
```

But if you want to avoid the second set of `colon` operators, you could flip the first side:

```
a = 1:2:9;
a = [a fliplr(a(1:end-1))]
```

But there you have another `colon`, and it's definitely more efficient to do it the first way.

Possibly by `c = 9; s = 2; b = 1:s:c-2; a = [b c fliplr(b)];` if `c-1` is divisible by `s`, but I don't see the point of complicating a simple operation like this... unless this is how you get your kicks. ;)

Comment: Wouldn't it be more efficient to do `a = 1:2:7; a = [a 9 fliplr(a)];`? Not very, obviously, but it avoids the extra colon.

Comment: @MrAzzaman Funny, I was just typing it up with variables for generality.  :)

Comment: If you wanted to be very general: `c = 9; s = 2; cs = floor(c/s);a = c + s*-abs((1:(2*cs+1))-(cs+1)) - rem(c-1,s);`. But that's just being silly.